# Using RequireJS with Graal

Tags: requirejs, graalvm

I am trying to use requireJS with GraalVM (Polyglot API) to load external JS code in my guest language scripts. 
The way I am going about this is by first running requirejs on the context:

```
    Context importCtx = Context.create();

    String libraryUrl = "file:/require.js";
    Source librarySource = Source.newBuilder("js", new URL(libraryUrl)).build();

    importCtx.eval(librarySource);
```

This results in require being added to the JS global, which allows me to use it in the following JS scripts running off that same context. I then simply run my guest script:

```
    String scriptUrl = "test.js";
    Source scriptSource = Source.newBuilder("js", new URL(scriptUrl)).build();

    importCtx.eval(scriptSource);
```

My guest script looks like this:

```
console.log("start of script");

require(['http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js'], function(mom) {
    console.log("inside require function");
    debugger;
    console.log(mom.now();
});

debugger;
console.log("end of script");
```

When running this script in a browser it works properly and prints the value of moment.now(). However, when running it off the Polyglot API, the JS runs, require is set correctly, but function(mom){} is never called. Basically I never see the "inside require function" message and the value of moment.now().

I have a feeling that this is happening because an error is occurring in loading the external resource (I have also tried loading off a file instead of the remote URL with no luck). However I cannot see any errors, even when running off chrome devtools with the inspect option enabled.

What could be the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example and noted that calling `require()` returns a function:

```
function localRequire(deps, callback, errback) { ...
```

I also get this behaviour when I just take your JavaScript code, use `load("require.js")` and then call `require()` - tried that on Rhino (1.7.7.2) and Nashorn (1.8.0_172). They don't seem to load the URL (moment.js) or call the callback - identical behaviour.

Am I missing anything?

Best,
Christian

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I am not familiar with the load() function you mention. The only load() function I know in this context is the JQuery AJAX load(), are you using JQuery? If you load this simple html code in a browser you will see require's expected behaviour. `<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.5/comments/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  require(['http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js'], function(mom) {
    console.log("Loaded moment. current time: " + mom.now());
  });
</script>` Let me know if this works for you. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, searching through the docs of GraalJS I found the load() function you are referring to: https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/blob/master/docs/user/JavaScriptCompatibility.md#loadsource Indeed this serves a similar purpose as requireJS. However, load simply executes the referenced file. If I am loading something like moment.js, as the guest language developer, I need to know that behind the scenes moment is adding itself to the globals as moment(). Ideally, I would have something like: `const mom = load('moment.js')` so that I can then use mom in my own code. Is that achievable?